# How to convert string object to Json in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nestjs

I want to convert this to json. I tried **JSON.parse()** but got this error

```
"{"status":"00","message":"OK","access_token":"2347682423567","customer":{"name":"John Doe","address":"Mr. John Doe 34 Tokai, leaflet. 7999.","util":"Demo Utility","minimumAmount":"13897"},"response_hash":"c43c9d74480f340f55156f6r5c56487v8w"}"
```

There is the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
```

That means I have to remove the first double quote. I don't know how to do remove it.

How can achieve this and get a valid json?

The code here below

````
 const url = `https://irecharge.com.ng/pwr_api_sandbox/v2/get_meter_info.php?vendor_code=${vendorcode}&reference_id=${reference_id}&meter=${meterNum}&disco=${discoName}&response_format=json&hash=${hash}`;

            const meterInfo = await this.httpService.get(url).toPromise();

            const data = meterInfo.data;


            const data = meterInfo.data;
            var ParsedData = JSON.parse(data.substring(1, data.length - 1))

            console.log(ParsedData);
            return ParsedData
    ```
I am supposed to pass response format, which should be json as you can see in the code
````

Comment: That isn't a valid JSON to begin with, this has nothing to do with Nest.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to achieve to convert string to a valid JSON

Comment: How'd you get the JSON in the first place? Are you needing to fix it programatically, or manually?

Comment: Its a response from an API endpoint. I want to convert to JSON so I can access the keys and values. I need it fixed programmatically

Comment: Can you show the API call in your code and what you're doing? It doesn't make sense that an API would return an invalid JSON as it wouldn't be serializable in the first place

Comment: Added code to my question

Comment: So when you `console.log(data)` you get that JSON?

Comment: yes, I got that invalid JSON

Answer (score 1):

**If that is truly the JSON you get back from the API, you need to raise an issue with them about the invalid JSON format they are sending.**

---

In the meantime, if you need to parse it, you can do `JSON.parse(data.substring(1, data.length - 1))` and you should have no problems (just tested locally).

I suspect the issue is rather that you are wrapping the response in `"` yourself, because as I said in the comments, that's an invalid JSON that cannot be serialized or consumed properly by anything.

Comment: var ParsedData = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Honestly, the data should already by in JSON format and you shouldn't even need this in the first place.

Comment: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: The issue is somewhere in your code. Without seeing it, who knows what's going on. You've shown the API returns valid JSON, so I don't understand why you're trying to re-parse it

Comment: I just discovered now that axios is header is  ``` 
connection:"close"
content-type:"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
date:"Mon, 01 Jun 2020 21:54:50 GMT"
server:"Apache"
transfer-encoding:"chunked" ```

Answer (score 0):

That URL is returning valid JSON. (I added dummy values to get a response) [source](https://irecharge.com.ng/pwr_api_sandbox/v2/get_meter_info.php?vendor_code=12&reference_id=34&meter=56&disco=disco&response_format=json&hash=hash)

> That means I have to remove the first double quote. I don't know how to do remove it.

I would try to figure out where the extra quotes are coming from in the first place rather than remove it after the fact.

Comment: Are you, by chance, doing something like `JSON.parse(\`"${data}"\`)`?

Comment: What I have in my code is JSON.parse(data)